# How to add an element at the beginning of a line in a file in Scala

Tags: scala, file, writefile

I have a file, e.g., like this:

```
// file_1.txt
10 2 3
20 5 6
30 8 9
```

I need to write a letter with a space before each line that meets a criterion regarding the first value / number in the line, e.g., if I give the value 20 then the file should look like this:

```
// file_1.txt
10 2 3
c 20 5 6
30 8 9
```

How I can achieve this in Scala?

This is what I am trying, till now:

```
import java.io._
import scala.io.Source

object Example_01_IO {

  val s = Source.fromFile("example_01_txt")

  val source = s.getLines()
  val destination = new PrintWriter(new File("des_example_01.txt"))
  val toComment = Array(-10, 20, -30)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    for (line <- source) {
      //if(line_begins_with_any_value_from_toComments_then_write_a_"c"_infront_of_that_line){
        println(line)
        destination.write("c" + line)
        destination.write("\n")
      //}

    }

    s.close()
    destination.close()

  }
}
```

I can write into another file, let's say, but I need to write in the same file, and only when a line meets a such condition.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What problems did you run into when you implemented it yourself?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. You are likely to have more luck on sites like http://freelancer.com

Comment: I made an edit (see up) on what I am trying. I wanted to keep the question simple for anyone that can help (and not to get offended. @Dima).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from what you have, all you really need to add is a way to check whether the current line starts with a number that is in your `Array`.

One way to do that is split the line on every space so you get a list of all the numbers on that line. Then take only the first of that list and convert it to an `Int`. Then you can simply check whether that `Int` is present in your `Array` of allowed numbers.

```
import java.io._
import scala.io.Source

object Example_01_IO {

  val s = Source.fromFile("example_01_txt")

  val source = s.getLines()
  val destination = new PrintWriter(new File("des_example_01.txt"))
  val toComment = Array(-10, 20, -30)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def startsWithOneOf(line: String, list: Array[Int]) = 
      list.contains(line.split(" ").head.toInt)

    for (line <- source) {
      val lineOut = if (startsWithOneOf(line, toComment)) s"c $line" else line
      destination.write(lineOut)
      destination.write("\n")
    }

    s.close()
    destination.close()

  }
}
```

Comment: In my example I was using 2 different files (to read from: `example_01_txt`, and to write to: `des_example_01_txt`). I tried your solution, by trying to write in the same file, _but_ when I use class `PrintWriter` the content of the file is replaced (meaning that, lines which are not satisfying the condition are removed), and when I am using `FileWriter(file, true)` the lines that fulfill the condition are appended. Is there a way to deal with this? Thanks a lot, btw.

Comment: I see. I wanted to avoid having extra files and maintaining them. Thank you, a lot!

Comment: @user4712458 I don't think it's possible to only replace certain lines. I think writing to files comes in 2 modes: a) append to file or b) write new file (possibly overwriting an existing file). So if you want to change a line in a file you'll have to write the entire file, including the unchanged lines. [There are ways to modify arbitrary bytes in files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), but that still doesn't allow you to insert new bytes in the middle without overwriting the existing bytes.

Comment: Ah, thanks for telling me about this opportunity! I didn't know about that, despite that, I think I am going to write in new files.